# Python - sum an array imported from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to sum up the values from a csv file after being placed into a list, i want to add them all together. The list as it goes:

```
'50', '51', '53', '55', '56', '56', '56', '61', '64', '67', '68', '71', '79', '81', '86', '86', '87', '94', '96', '98', '99' 'Score'
```

The code gets these values from the csv and places the vales into a list

```
import csv

f=open('IT_Programming_data.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
score = [] 
for row in csv_f:"score"      
  score.append(row[1])
  a = score
  b = sum(a)
  print (b)
f.close()
```

When i attempt to sum up the list i get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

sum works when you do:

```
a = [1,3,4]

b = sum(a)

print (b)
```

Which returns '8'

How do i make it work with a list imported from the csv, i have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to add a string and a number which will raise a ValueError, try this code to deal with the Exception:

```
import csv

f = open('IT_Programming_data.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
score = [] 
for row in csv_f:
  try:
    num = int(row[1].strip()) # try to switch type
    score.append(num)
  except Exception,error: # fail to switch, print error
    print(error)

b = sum(score)
print(b)

f.close()
```

Comment: I'm pretty new at this now I'm getting indentation errors for unexpected indentations.

Comment: I'm using python 3.4 could that be the problem? Should i use a different version?

Comment: It should not be  indentation errors, I use space to indent, you may try to use space.

Comment: After playing round i don't think it was the indentations i had to change  except ValueError,error TO except ValueError as error:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your lists entries are not formatted right. You can catch this bug for example by printing in the contents in the loop:

```
import csv

f=open('testlist.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
score = [] 
for row in csv_f:      
    print(row)
    score.append(int(row[1].strip().strip("'")))

a = score
b = sum(a)

print (b)
f.close()
```

The output will be something like `["'50'", " '51'", " '53'", " '55'", " '56'", " '56'", " '56'",..., " '99' 'Score'"]`
So you can see here that you have entries sometimes starting with a whitespace and they include additional " ' ". You have to clean up your list by removing the last entry, then you have to get rid of the whitespaces, and then you have to get rid of the additional " ' ". Then you have to cast this all to int. This is done in the loop above

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use try-except in a loop. It hurts the performance a lot and looks really unprofessional especially when there is a built-in `isdigit()`.

```
import csv

f = open('IT_Programming_data.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
score = [] 
for row in csv_f:
  if row[1].isdigit():
    num = int(row[1]) # try to switch type
    score.append(num)

b = sum(score)
print(b)

f.close()
```

Comment: This works too i just had to add a colon to the end of isdigit(), Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
b= [sum(int(x)) for x in a]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.